How can one count how many pixels a GIF image has via command line?
I use Ubuntu. I have a large number of GIF images. How can one count how many pixels a GIF image has via command line?

Not worth a full answer, but ffprobe (part of the ffmpeg suite) includes the image width and height in the info it displays.  (It's mainly intended for audio and video, but handles a huge range of formats including still images.)

I'm interested to know what you want this number for? Are you aware that some frames of a GIF only update/overwrite a few pixels that have changed since the previous one, i.e. they are not complete? As such, the number of pixels is not really the height * width * numberOfFrames.

@MarkSetchell because of the new pixel limit for gif on SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401421/178179; https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/399802/178179; https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/399756/178179

You can use  imagemagick package. Command like this will print the dimensions (in pixels) of a image:
identify -format '%w %h' example.gif

And the result will be (example):
128 1024

And as suggested in comment to calculate the number of pixels you can use command like:
identify -format '%W %H * + ' example.gif | dc -e0 -f- -ep


... or something like identify -format '%w %h * + ' example.gif | dc -e0 -f- -ep to do the arithmetic and handle multi-frame (animated) gifs

@steeldriver, for multiframe I am not sure it's required because AFAIK the frames have same dimention

TBH I just based it on the OP's solution - I guess one could do identify -format '%w * %h * %n\n' example.gif | head -n 1 | bc instead

... fwiw I just tested with j7q3w.gif from the OP's answer and it looks like %w %h does vary by frame, but %W %H (which the imagemagick documentation refers to as the page or canvas geometry) are fixed. The first frame appears to have %w %h and %W %H equal, so either summing %W * %H with dc or calculating %w * %h * %n for the first frame (with head and bc) agree with the OP's 96738345 value.

I eventually used this Python script to get the number of pixels in a GIF image:
from PIL import Image
image_path = 'random.gif'
img = Image.open(image_path)
total_pixels = 0
frame_count = 0

# Iterate through each frame in the GIF
try:
    while True:
        img.seek(frame_count)
        width, height = img.size
        total_pixels += width * height
        frame_count += 1
except EOFError:
    pass

print(f'Number of pixels in {image_path}: {total_pixels:,} pixels')

Example on https://i.sstatic.net/j7q3w.gif:
Number of pixels in j7q3w.gif: 96,738,345 pixels


Is it possible you can use this script to go through the database of former SE Imgur images and make a statistical distribution of the number of pixels in each animated image filetype?

@gparyani Yes that was my plan actually. I wanted to give some distribution information when asking https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401948/178179. But the hostility of some users, mods and employees convinced me to focus my energy elsewhere for now. And even if we show that x percent of gifs are above 50M pixels, some people will keep arguing in favor of pixel art.

You can also just use the file command on some image types, it works for .GIF and .PNG:
    # file myimage.gif
    # myimage.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 1295 x 264

Multiplying the width by height (those last two numbers) gives the pixel count.
This could be automated with a pipe through awk:
    # file myimage.gif | awk '{print $NF * $(NF-2)}'   
    # 341880

To run over a bunch of files:
    # find . -iname \*.gif | while read filename; do pixels=$( file "${filename}" | awk '{print $NF * $(NF-2)}' ); echo "${filename}: ${pixels} pixels"; done

EDIT: Incorporate @Romeo Ninov's comment.

When having space(s) in filename you can better use: awk '{print $NF * $(NF-2)}'

The final frame of an animated GIF can be addressed as animated.gif[-1] in ImageMagick. So you can get the width and height of the final frame using %W and %H and also the scene/frame number of that frame using %s - although this starts at zero. So the formula for total number of pixels is:
identify -format "%W * %H * (%s+1)\n" example.gif[-1] | bc
96738345


Or, maybe more simply with exiftool:
exiftool -p '$ImageWidth * $ImageHeight * $FrameCount' example.gif | bc
96738345


Another way... coalesce all the frames to their full size, convert to grey and a header-free stream of 1 byte/pixel, then count the bytes:
magick animated.gif -coalesce -depth 8 gray:- | wc -c
96738345


Another way... coalesce all the frames to their full size, append them all together and work out the product of width and height without calling any external utilities:
magick animated.gif -coalesce -append -format "%[fx:w*h]" -precision 10 info:
96738345

